# count nonempty cells in a row excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

Having trouble with syntax while trying to count nonempty cells in a row(in this example, row two), excel vba.

Have tried .rows(2:2)   .rows(2)   .cells(B1:B999)  received errors with all three.

```
    Dim intCount As Integer
    intCount = CountA(ActiveSheet.Rows(2, 2))
```

Comment: CountA is a native excel function - to access it within VBA, you must preface it with WorksheetFunction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CountA` is not a VBA function, it is a worksheet function. Try this:

```
Dim intCount as integer
intCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Activesheet.Rows(2))
```